# Palindrome Linkedlist using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

Indexing starts from 0.
Input format : Linked list elements (separated by space and terminated by -1)

There is some runtime error on one hidden test case. `main()` is taking input and passing `head`.

```
public class Solution {
    static String s1="",s2="";
    public static boolean isPalindrome_2(LinkedListNode<Integer> head) {
        if (head != null) {
            s1 = s1 + head.data;
            isPalindrome_2(head.next);
            s2 = s2 + head.data;
        }
        if (s1.equals(s2))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

How the algorithm is supposed to work: `s1` will store the string containing all data. `s2` will store data in reverse manner since it is after recursive function. Then the strings can be compared.

Comment: I guess you should do something with the result of the recursive call.

Comment: s1 will store the string containing all data.s2 will store data in reverse manner , because it is after recursive function. Then the strings can be compared

Comment: Hello, please clarify what the runtime error is, does it happen for any input data? It seems you need to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided a reproducible example, I have not been able to run your code and verify any hypotheses. So this is from inspection alone.

1. If the numbers in the list ar 1 and 11, it is not a palindrome. Yet your string `s1` and `s2` should both become `111`, that is equal, so your method should return `true`.
2. You are not testing for the -1 at the end. Shouldn’t you?

BTW I don’t see any indexing and I don’t see any space between elements.

I also have not understood how a runtime error can occur, sorry. Again, running your code might have given me a greater chance.